# Thrown error after upgrade project to API 25

Tags: android, api, crash, inputstream

I'm building a new app in android studio to show messages from an external server. Yesterday I decided to build a BottomNavigationView within main activity which is supported by API 25. So I've changed app's API from 24 to 25. Everything looks fine in compilation schedule but when app runs it crashes with the following code:

```
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                               com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                                Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                                   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

Here is the gradle module app:

```
`apply plug`in: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.newapplications"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

I've searched over the net but i didn't find anything useful yet. Someone can help me?

Comment: What is your evidence that this stack trace came from your app?

Comment: from whom it should be come? I've not attached any class cause I believe this error comes from some other internal conflicts, but I can be wrong. should I post the whole main activity?

Comment: "from whom it should be come?" -- if *your app* is crashing, the stack trace would come from *your process*.

Comment: @firstofthebadones Have you resolved this problem? I'm getting this strange error!